# how can I change the number of cursors using multiple cursors mc/mark-next-lines?

Tags: multiple-cursors

I encounter many situations where I'd like to use `mc/mark-next-lines` but I don't know how to change the number of cursors. When I do `C-u 2 mc/mark-next-lines` I get 7 cursors instead of 3.

It would be neat if I could pass a two to this command to get 2 cursors. I don't see any sense in that bevhaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `mc/mark-next-like-this`? If no region, marks next lines depending on argument.

Comment: this is the command I was looking for. I wouldn't have expected this functionality with this name. thx !

Comment: @Juancho: Please post your comment as an answer. OP: Please consider accepting that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `mc/mark-next-like-this`.

If you have no active region, then it will select one (or more) extra lines.

Documentation:

> Find and mark the next part of the buffer matching the currently
>   active region If no region is active add a cursor on the next line
>   With negative ARG, delete the last one instead. With zero ARG, skip
>   the last one and mark next.

I have it bound to <kbd>C-x x</kbd>.